# Missing Decals After Purchasing

Tags: stickers

Good day,
I just bought a brand new [Lego Speed Champion Toyota GR Supra 7690](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=76901-1). After reaching home and unboxing it, I realized that my set was missing the decals. Is there any way that I can get the decals for my Lego set?

Comment: Contact the store, or try customer support.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem with my [McLaren Elva](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=76902-1), the printing of the stickers was severely misaligned with the cutting.

I used the [Lego Customer Service Missing Bricks form](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/replacementparts/missing/) to report the problem and they sent me a replacement free of charge, not even shipping.

Side note: It did take about two months to arrive, likely due to the pandemic and the fact that I'm out of the way in New Zealand. But I hope you get yours sooner.

Comment: Missing bricks service often takes several weeks at the best of times even if you live close to one of their distributing warehouses.

Comment: @Tonny That is a little disappointing to hear

Comment: I've used missing bricks twice, and in both cases, the turnaround has been < 2 weeks.